# How to merge cells in a single column?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Given the sample code using [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/getting-started/) with Vue 3

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";
import { ref } from "vue";

const columnDefs = ref([
  {
    field: "person",
  },
  {
    field: "car",
  },
]);

const rowData = ref([
  {
    person: "person-1",
    car: "car-1",
  },
  {
    person: "person-1",
    car: "car-2",
  },
  {
    person: "person-1",
    car: "car-3",
  },
  {
    person: "person-2",
    car: "car-4",
  },
  {
    person: "person-3",
    car: "car-5",
  },
  {
    person: "person-3",
    car: "car-6",
  },
]);
</script>

<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
  >
  </ag-grid-vue>
</template>
```

You will get the following output

[image]

I could group the table based on person but is there a way to merge cells in a single column?

[image]

I think I can't use [row-spanning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-spanning/) for a single column definition because inside the `rowSpan` function it is not possible to tell ag-grid to combine multiple cells of a single column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

After spending a few hours on this requirement, I came up with the solution.

Here are the steps which I performed **:**

- To implement `rowSpan`, You have to manipulate the `rowData` so that it will contain the `person` property only in the first occurance object. As a result, When we will apply the `rowSpan` based on the length it will not take that length for each same person name. This is how I manipulated the `rowData` **:**

  ```js
      const uniq = {};
      const rowData = [{
        person: "person-1",
        car: "car-1",
      }, {
        person: "person-1",
        car: "car-2",
      }, {
        person: "person-1",
        car: "car-3",
      }, {
        person: "person-2",
        car: "car-4",
      }, {
        person: "person-3",
        car: "car-5",
      }, {
        person: "person-3",
        car: "car-6",
  }];

  rowData.forEach(obj => {
      !uniq[obj.person] ? uniq[obj.person] = true : delete obj.person;
  });

  console.log(rowData);
  ```
- Now, Created a `rowSpan` function which is basically used to return the length of the objects contains occurrence of same person names.

  ```
  function rowSpan(params) {
    const person = params.data.person;
    const gridData = getData(); // getData() with return the original rowData array.
    return gridData.filter((e) => e.person === person).length;
  }
  ```
- At the end, for styling the `rowSpan` columns. I used these styles (refer from [`here`](https://ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/row-spanning/#row-spanning-complex-example))

  ```
  .show-cell {
    background: white;
    border-left: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
  }
  ```

  This is how the `columnDefs` for `person` object looks like **:**

  ```
  {
    field: "person",
    rowSpan: rowSpan,
    cellClassRules: { 'show-cell': 'value !== undefined' }
  }
  ```

Live Demo **:** [`Row Spanning Demo`](https://plnkr.co/edit/MEOCjIcffG74x1Kl)

Comment: thanks for your answer @Rohit Jindai :) Unfortunately the row manipulation looks pretty hacky. I'm hoping for a "native" solution ... ( wasn't able to find one in the docs tough ... )

Comment: @baitendbidz I created this working demo by taking the reference from docs only and there is no harm to use this solution. In docs those are straight forward solutions but our case is different. That's the reason i came up with customized one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure row-spanning will not work? Can you try to implement this?

```
function rowSpan(params) {
  const person = params.data.person;
  return rowData.value.filter((e) => e.person === person).length;
}

const columnDefs = ref([
  {
    field: "person",
    rowSpan: rowSpan,
  },
  {
    field: "car",
  },
]);
```

Comment: I implemented `rowSpan: params => rowData.value.filter((e) => e.person === params.data.person).length` and nothing changed. Although when logging the length: 3 times 3, 1 time 1 and 2 times 2 ( as expected )

Comment: @baitendbidz Do you have suppressRowTransform set to "true" in gridOptions?

Comment: yes, I added `:suppress-row-transform="true"` to the grid component but that didn't help